# Creating an object of a random sub class in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I'm pretty new to C# so please excuse my beginners question. I have allready searched but haven't found the solution I wanted.

I have an abstract class and several sub classes of it. Let's just say subclass1 to subclass9.

What I want to do now is to generate an object from a random subclass. Actually I'd like to have some lists including a preselection of those classes. Like: List1 including sub classes 1, 3, 4 and 6, List2 including 1, 2, 5, 6 and 9 and so on. So I can say anytime: Give me a random object from List2.

My idea was to generate arrays and putting those subclasses into them, then selecting a random element of the array. But that didn't work out for me. I haven't figured out how to fill the arrays with objects, so I am not sure if this isn't possible or I just haven't found the right syntax. Can anyone give me a hind on how to generate those lists?

Since I am allready asking: Is there an easy way to give the objects in the lists different probabilities to occour?

Edit:
Actually I am trying to understand how to handle a something like this in general in different situation.

For example: I have an abstract class *items*. I might have different sub classes like *potion*, *dagger*, *scroll* and so on. Now I might want to generate some random loot after a fight, maybe two random items. But I don't want to drop any item. For example I don't want a bear to drop daggers or scrolls, but more something like bear skin and some bones left in his cave. So I need different lists of possible loot I can generate random drops from.

How can I do that? Like said I tried to put classes into an array, but I haven't figured out how to do that. Not even sure that was the right idea how to do it.

I figured how to put specific objects into an array or list. But I don't want to generate 20 objects to randomly pick two of them and destruct the rest of them.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: It's unclear exactly what your goal is and what you're stuck on.  Are you having problems picking an object from a list?  Creating a random type of object?  Creating a list that can hold different kinds of objects?  Please [edit] your post to include only *one* question and clarify what you need help with.

Comment: *"I tried to put classes into an array"* - What do you mean by that? Show the code you tried (and explain what errors, etc you got)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `factory method` with `table of methods` patterns.

```
private static Func<Item>[] tableOfMethods =
{
     () => new Potion()
}

public static Item GetRandomItem() 
{
    var randomIndex = generate index here....
    return tableOfMethods[randomIndex]();
}
```

P.S. syntax of array creation can be wrong here, writing it from mobile.

Comment: Thank you. That pointed me in a direction I can work with.